# Covariance of two random variable, with one uniformly distributed and the other dependent on it.

Tags: probability, covariance

Problem from actuarial Exam P:

> Let $X$ and $Y$ denote the values of two stocks at the end of a five-year period. $X$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $(0,12)$. Given $X=x$, $Y$ is uniformly distributed on the interval $(0,x)$. Determine $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)$ according to this model.

I know that $\operatorname{Cov}(X,Y)=E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$, and   $E[X]=6$.

So ultimately my question is that when I am finding $E[Y]$, I don't understand how $f(x,y)$ becomes $1/12x$. Is it $1/12 \cdot 1/x$? If correct, why?

Comment: Please avoid the word "help" in the title; it is redundant. Instead, make the title more descriptive of the actual problem. Also, see the [MathJax reference](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 4):

Note that $Y=ZX$ where $Z$ is uniform on $(0,1)$ and independent of $X$, hence $XY=ZX^2$ and $\mathrm{Cov}(X,Y)$ is $$E(ZX^2)-E(X)E(ZX)=E(Z)E(X^2)-E(Z)E(X)^2=E(Z)\mathrm{Var}(X).$$
Can you finish this?

Answer (score 0):

It's because $f(x,y)= f(y|x) f(x)$. But $f(y|x)= \frac{1}{x}$ and $f(x)=\frac{1}{12}$.

Make sure you understand this! You'll need it for P, and you'll need it again for C.

**Note**: This seems the wrong forum for this question. You should ask it over at [Actuarial Outpost](http://www.actuarialoutpost.com/actuarial_discussion_forum/forumdisplay.php?f=19).

Comment: Actually, $f(x|y)$ is quite different from $f(x)$. (And I fully agree that one should make sure that one understands this... :-) but not that this is the wrong forum for such a question.)

Comment: "But $f(x|y)$ in this case equals $f(x)=\frac{1}{12}$." Once again, *absolutely not*.

Comment: Sorry; math blindness. Corrected. Thanks!